# Is It Possible To Have Only Selected User Account Data With LDAP?

Tags: ldap

A web application is with the LDAP as an authentication source. The application is used by a dozen of internal users. On the other hand, the LDAP setup pulls far more what is needed user account data into the application. Because the application is deployed outside of the company networks, security is a big topic for production. Is it possible to have only selected user account data with LDAP?

Comment: Yes. but, Tell us what you have tried and show logs or results and Read:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I should mention that we already set up user search based and user filter to narrow down the user account data. Internal users from different teams will use the app.  We also use OAuth2 as an authentication source in the system. With OAuth2, an application only gets user accounts for those who sign in. That would be an ideal situation for our LDAP.